# Can I style my ngx-bootstrap element from my components .css file?

Tags: html, css, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using a ngx-bootstrap 'alert' component. And I'd like to style the alert message, but adding the styles to the compnents .css file doesn't do anything.

question - ngx-bootstrap says to style do this below but I'd like to know if it can be done from the component .css file?

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/alerts#local-styling

```js
styles: [
    `
  :host >>> .alert-md-local {
    background-color: #009688;
    border-color: #00695C;
    color: #fff;
  }
  `
  ]
```

ex.

```css
.alert {
  border-radius: 0px !important; // doesn't do anything
  margin-bottom: 0px !important; // doesn't do anything
}
```

```html
<alert [type]="alert.type" [dismissible]="dismissible" [dismissOnTimeout]="alert.timeout" class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">{{ alert.msg }}</alert>
```

Comment: Try `alert { border... }` With no dot `.` cose `<alert>` Is not an class. Learn more about targeting in CSS.

Comment: that is incorrect. .alert IS a class that is part of that bootstrap component...Learn how ngx-bootstrap converts to it's appropriate element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-deep` for this. Though it is mentioned in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) that it will be deprecated soon, there's a lot of discussion going on about a good alternate solution for the same. Here's the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160).

For now, `ng-deep` still works.

```css
:host ::ng-deep .alert {
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: well, based on my OP I don't even need ::ng-deep as I show above

Comment: I'm just looking to see if there is a pure .css solution